# Is there a way to disable a CKeditor instance (i.e. make it read-only) and then enable it?

Tags: ckeditor

I'm working on a webapp where I want to have INPUTs initially disabled, initiate an Ajax request to populate the components the INPUTs belong to, and enable the INPUTs as live after the data has been populated.

Is there a way that this or something comparable can be done with CKeditor? If worst comes to worst I can have just a TEXTAREA that is disabled and call CKEDITOR.replace() when the data is ready to populate it?

Are there options for a temporarily read-only CKeditor instance that is made normally editably by a subsequent call?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a method [`editor.setReadOnly()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setReadOnly) which allows to enable and disable the read-only mode. There's also a config option [`config.readOnly`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-readOnly) which allows to set the initial state of this feature.

Usage is simple:

```
editor.setReadOnly( true ); // Enable the RO mode.
editor.setReadOnly( false ); // Disables the RO mode.
```

See also the [live sample](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/readonly.html).